# How do I add range to one of my query requirments?

Tags: sqlite

I have two tables.  The first has a series of data with three columns [z, s, c] call it tblbaseline. The second table has the same structure [z,s,c] call it tbldatalog.  I want to find records in tblbaseline that match tbldatalog using column s and are similar to those in tbldatalog but not necessarily identical.  I can pull all matching records based on column s, but how do I additionally filter for column c given that I want any record from tblbaseline that is plus or minus 5 of the corresponding record in tbldatalog.

This code gives me all matching records based on column s and c:

```
select baseline.count from baseline LEFT JOIN data_log where baseline.sample=data_log.sample AND baseline.count=data_log.count;
```

This code does not work...

```
select baseline.count from baseline LEFT JOIN data_log where baseline.sample=data_log.sample AND baseline.count>= data_log.count -3 OR baseline.count<= data_log.count +3;
```

Here is the table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE baseline (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, zone INTEGER, sample INTEGER, count INTEGER, sqlTimeStamp DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);

CREATE TABLE data_log (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, zone INTEGER, sample INTEGER, count INTEGER, sqlTimeStamp DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

Here is the table data:

```
sqlite> select * from baseline;
```

1|2|1|186|2015-07-24 16:31:38
2|2|2|183|2015-07-24 16:31:47
3|2|3|170|2015-07-24 16:32:01
4|2|4|165|2015-07-24 16:32:12
5|5|1|115|2015-07-24 16:32:26
7|5|2|113|2015-07-24 16:33:12
8|5|3|111|2015-07-24 16:33:23
9|5|4|109|2015-07-24 16:33:33

```
sqlite> select * from data_log;
```

1|0|1|115|2015-07-24 16:34:09
2|0|2|113|2015-07-24 16:34:18
3|0|3|111|2015-07-24 16:34:28
4|0|4|109|2015-07-24 16:34:42

The following queries and the results:

```
sqlite> select baseline.count from baseline LEFT JOIN data_log where baseline.sample=data_log.sample AND baseline.count=data_log.count;
```

115
113
111
109

```
sqlite> select baseline.count from baseline LEFT JOIN data_log where baseline.sample=data_log.sample AND baseline.count between data_log.count+60 AND data_log.count-60;
```

The query with the +/- 60 condition should return records 5-9 and additionally record 4 of the baseline table.

Answer (score 0):

LEFT JOIN works only one the join condition in the ON clause.

And as shown in the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html), AND has a higher precedence than OR, so your query is the same as:

```
select baseline.count
from baseline
LEFT JOIN data_log
where (    baseline.sample  = data_log.sample 
       AND baseline.count  >= data_log.count - 3)
   OR baseline.count <= data_log.count + 3;
```

You should insert the correct parentheses:

```
select baseline.count
from baseline
LEFT JOIN data_log
ON   baseline.sample  = data_log.sample 
 AND (baseline.count >= data_log.count - 3 OR
       baseline.count <= data_log.count + 3   );
```

or just use BETWEEN:

```
SELECT baseline.count
FROM baseline
LEFT JOIN data_log
ON baseline.sample  = data_log.sample AND
   baseline.count BETWEEN data_log.count - 3 AND data_log.count + 3;
```